# django 1.11 html "href" doesn't work with template url

Tags: django, href

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^index', views.index, name='index'),
```

my views.py

```
def index(request):
return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

index.html

```
<ul>
<li><a href="{% url 'all_contacts' %}"></a>All Contacts</li>
</ul>
```

My page with the href hyperlink not working

[image]

The source:

[image]

So I had a look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp and it indicates that relative paths only work if it's pointing to a file. Not sure what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
<a href="{% url 'all_contacts' %}"></a>All Contacts
```

Your `<a>` tag is empty. You want to put the link text **inside** the tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'all_contacts' %}">All Contacts</a>
```

Oh and while we're at it:

> I had a look at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp and it indicates that relative paths only work if it's pointing to a file

The exact text is: "A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")". But that's still complete BS, there's no notion of file here, a "relative url" (actually an absolute or relative path) is resolved against the current domain (and the current path if it's a relative path), how the resulting url is served depends on the software serving this resource. FWIW, Django's urls (the one built by the `{% url %}` tag) are always absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
<a href="{% url 'all_contacts' %}"><li>All Contacts</li></a>
</ul>
```

use this as href needs to be before the `<li>` tag

Comment: This is invalid html, and NO the problem is not that the `<a>` tag "needs to be before the `<li>`.

Comment: yeah i did get invalid html when i checked with the w3 online checker.